# Show that the set of $\alpha$-H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder continuous functions is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

A function $f$ is $\alpha$-H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder continuous if $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C |x - y|^\alpha $ for some $C \geq 0$ and $\forall$ $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x - y| < 1$.

Define the norm:
$||f||_{C^\alpha} = ||f||_\infty + \sup \limits_{\substack{x, y \in \mathbb{R} \\ |x - y| < 1}} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha}$

Let $C^\alpha(\mathbb{R})$ =  the set of $\alpha$-H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder continuous functions = $\{ f : ||f||_{C^\alpha} < \infty \}$.

Show that $\left ( C^\alpha(\mathbb{R}) , ||.||_{C^\alpha}  \right ) $ is a Banach space for any $0 < \alpha \leq 1$.

I already showed $C^\alpha$ is a normed vector space. Need to show completeness as follows:

Consider a cauchy sequence $\left ( f_n \in C^\alpha(X) \right )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n, m > N$, we have $||f_n - f_m||_{C^\alpha} < \epsilon$ $\implies $ $$||f_n - f_m||_\infty + \sup_{\substack{x, y \in X \\ |x - y| < 1}} \frac{|f_n(x) - f_m(x) - f_n(y) + f_m(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} < \epsilon$$

Need some help/pointers to proceed further. I also know that $\alpha$-H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder continuous functions are uniformly continuous for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must at least have $\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$, so for any $x$, 
\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|<\epsilon,~~~~n,m>N,
\end{align*}
so the sequence of scalars $(f_{n}(x))$ is Cauchy and hence $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)$ exists, and 
\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon,~~~~n>N.
\end{align*}
Also for any $x,y$ such that $d(x,y)<1$, 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)-f_{n}(y)+f_{m}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}<\epsilon,~~~~n,m>N,
\end{align*}
taking $m\rightarrow\infty$ we have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|f_{n}(x)-f(x)-f_{n}(y)+f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\leq\epsilon,~~~~n>N.
\end{align*}
The rest is easy.

Comment: Thanks. So this shows $f_n \to f$ with respect to $||.||_{C^\alpha}$ norm. But how to deduce $f \in C^\alpha$, i.e. $||f||_{C^\alpha} < \infty$? Should I just write out $||f||_{C^\alpha}$ and replace instances of $f$ by $\lim_n f_n$? Not sure how this would work out.

Comment: Use triangle inequality that $\|f\|\leq\|f-f_{n}\|+\|f_{n}\|<\infty$.